# Is ChromaticityPlot3D bugged in V11 with regard to FillingStyle?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

On Mac OSX 10.10.5, a large number of the examples for `ChromaticityPlot3D` do not appear as expected including:

**Opacity in FillingStyle:**

```
ChromaticityPlot3D["sRGB", FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

[image: translucent]

**FillingStyle -> None:**

```
ChromaticityPlot3D["RGB", FillingStyle -> None]
```

[image: no fill]

**Plotting multiple colorspaces:**

```
ChromaticityPlot3D[{"WideGamutRGB", "sRGB"}]
```

[image: multiple colorspaces]

The docs for [`ChromaticityPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChromaticityPlot3D.html) will show you the expected behaviour - essentially no transparency is being produced when it should be!

The problem does not occur for 10.3 or 11.1.

I'll let someone else confirm before looking to add a bug tag.

Comment: I can't reproduce in 10.4, 11.1, or 11.2. Prolly a version-specific hiccup?

Comment: All the examples work as expected in macOS 10.13.1 and MMA 11.2